# Sort Only numbers from alphanumeric string in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sort last three numbers in following Pattern.

```
Pattern: 1AB23CD456
```

I have same pattern strings stored in mysql database.

**Output I get:**

1ab33cd401

1ab22cd201

1ab11cd101

1ab01cd301

**Output I want:**

1ab01cd101

1ab11cd201

1ab22cd301

1ab33cd401

And Before sorting last 3 numbers , I would like to sort numbers between **ab** and **cd**

I am using PHP server side scripting language, if required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort the results with last three numbers you can use mysql's [*RIGHT()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY RIGHT(numbers,3)
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a51c1/1)

Comment: Thanks It worked, Do you know what if i want to sort numbers between **ab** and **cd** before sorting last 3 numbers.

Comment: @hsaka . . . You should ask another question.  Your original question has been answered.

Comment: @hsaka Gordon is right you should ask another question for this but i am not sure for the occurrence of ab and cd's position ,if its same then you can do so [*fiddle demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a51c1/6)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks for your help, But **ab** and **cd** can be any character combination.